# Scala synchronized consumer producer

Tags: multithreading, scala, producer-consumer

I want to implement something like the producer-consumer problem (with only one information transmitted at a time), but I want the producer to wait for someone to take his message before leaving.

Here is an example that doesn't block the producer but works otherwise.

```
class Channel[T]
{
private var _msg : Option[T] = None

def put(msg : T) : Unit =
{
    this.synchronized
    {
        waitFor(_msg == None)

        _msg = Some(msg)

        notifyAll
    }
}

def get() : T =
{
    this.synchronized
    {
        waitFor(_msg != None)

        val ret = _msg.get

        _msg = None

        notifyAll

        return ret
    }
}

private def waitFor(b : => Boolean) =
    while(!b) wait
}
```

How can I changed it so the producers gets blocked (as the consumer is) ?

I tried to add another waitFor at the end of but sometimes my producer doesn't get released.

For instance, if I have `put ; get || get ; put`, most of the time it works, but sometimes, the first `put` is not terminated and the left thread never even runs the `get` method (I print something once the `put` call is terminated, and in this case, it never gets printed).

Comment: Are you looking for something like `BlockingQueue`?: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

Comment: @AlekseyIzmailov given *with only one information transmitted at a time* [Exchanger looks to be more suitable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html)

Comment: No, I'm not looking for a blocking queue, I want both participants to be blocked until the exchange is done (and the others are waiting outside).
It might be a little like exchanger but I'd like to do it myself… Isn't there a way to fix what I've already done ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is why you should use a standard class, [SynchronousQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html) in this case.

If you really want to work through your problematic code, start by giving us a failing test case or a stack trace from when the put is blocking.

Comment: I updated my message to show a code sample that worked but didn't cause the putter to wait.
It is indeed a SynchronousQueue I'm looking for (I didn't know they worked that way), anyway, I would like to understand how I could fix my code to have the same behavior.

I updated my message to show you.

I totally agree about the asymmetry which is quite odd…

Comment: ' SynchronousQueue' does not seem to be an actual queue.

Comment: @Martin In what sense? It implements the `Queue` interface, but the docs note that 'A synchronous queue does not have any internal capacity, not even a capacity of one.'

Comment: And that's cool, because I don't want a Queue at all, I just want a channel to send a message, but only if there are two threads to participate at the same time.

Comment: If this is a learning exercise, get it working with basic `synchronized` blocks first (you are not far), then see if you can modify it to use `notify` instead of `notifyAll` (for better efficiency), or introduce higher-level constructs from `java.util.concurrent`

Comment: Anyway, I want to give it a try, but how can I use `SynchronousQueue`? I tried `import scala.actors.threadpool.SynchronousQueue`which works in REPL but doesn't with sbt... I tried adding `libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-actors" % "2.10.0-M6"`in my build.sbt file but no can do… I still get _object actors is not a member of package scala_

Comment: @Sheeft Wrong `SynchronousQueue`, you want the one from `java.util.concurrent`.

Comment: Ah, I thought it was meant to be the same but only ported in Scala.
Anyway, I think I have all I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by means of a BlockingQueue descendant whose producer put () method creates a semaphore/event object that is queued up with the passed message and then the producer thread waits on it.

The consumer get() method extracts a message from the queue and signals its semaphore, so allowing its original producer to run on.

This allows a 'synchronous queue' with actual queueing functionality, should that be what you want?

Comment: I must say I have thought of semaphores, but in this case, wouldn't it be the exact same as having a mutex (so as using `this.synchronized`) ?
Plus, I don't want a queue at all, I want it to be the least deterministic (if several `get`and/or `put`were to be called at the same time).

Answer (score 0):

I came up with something that appears to be working.

```
class Channel[T]
{
    class Transfer[A]
    {
        protected var _msg : Option[A] = None

        def msg_=(a : A) = _msg = Some(a)
        def msg : A =
        {
            // Reading the message destroys it
            val ret = _msg.get
            _msg = None
            return ret
        }

        def isEmpty = _msg == None
        def notEmpty = !isEmpty
    }

    object Transfer {
        def apply[A](msg : A) : Transfer[A] =
        {
            var t = new Transfer[A]()
            t.msg = msg
            return t
        }
    }

    // Hacky but Transfer has to be invariant
    object Idle extends Transfer[T]

    protected var offer : Transfer[T] = Idle
    protected var request : Transfer[T] = Idle

    def put(msg : T) : Unit =
    {
        this.synchronized
        {
            // push an offer as soon as possible
            waitFor(offer == Idle)
            offer = Transfer(msg)

            // request the transfer
            requestTransfer

            // wait for the transfer to go (ie the msg to be absorbed)
            waitFor(offer isEmpty)

            // delete the completed offer
            offer = Idle
            notifyAll
        }
    }

    def get() : T =
    {
        this.synchronized
        {
            // push a request as soon as possible
            waitFor(request == Idle)
            request = new Transfer()

            // request the transfer
            requestTransfer

            // wait for the transfer to go (ie the msg to be delivered)
            waitFor(request notEmpty)
            val ret = request.msg

            // delete the completed request
            request = Idle
            notifyAll
            return ret
        }
    }

    protected def requestTransfer()
    {
        this.synchronized
        {
            if(offer != Idle && request != Idle)
            {
                request.msg = offer.msg
                notifyAll
            }
        }
    }

    protected def waitFor(b : => Boolean) =
     while(!b) wait
}
```

It has the advantage of respecting symmetry between producer and consumer but it is a bit longer than what I had before.

Thanks for your help.

Edit : It is better but still not safe…